# Fire event when list variable changes in C#

Tags: c#, listview, event-handling, treeview

I've been looking into and researching ways of approaching this and I've got a working solution that seems redundant because I have place duplicate functions throughout the tool. Is there a way to make this simple example fire an event which updates my UI each and every time the  variable is changed? In this case if the user hits 'Add' or 'Clear' i want it to update the UI since it changes the variable .

[image]

```
namespace exampleList
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<string> files = new List<string>();

        public void SetCounter()
        {
            uiCounter.Text = files.Count().ToString(); 
        }

        public void SetUI()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(f);
                TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(f);
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
            }
        }

        private void uiAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            files.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());

            SetCounter();
            SetUI();
        }

        private void uiClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            files.Clear();
            SetUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of a `List<T>`

Comment: So, the user clicks a button.  Your code adds an item to a List.  You need the List to tell your code that the code added something?

Comment: i just want to fire and event when the list variable is changed